# Where should I place the "Actions" button?

Tags: usability, mobile, ios, user-expectation

I'm building an iOS application aiming to let user create meetings and wait for some participants.

Basically, when the user is on the meetings list page, he can click to open a specific one.
In standard terms, it's the "show" screen.

The screen currently looks like this:

[image]

When clicking on the "Actions" button, it opens a standard iPhone menu like this:

[image]  (from Google, not related to my app)

Note that this "popup" overlaps the tabs at the very bottom, that is expected.

At first glance, it sounds great, but the particularity of my app is that the tabs at the bottom are pretty large (original design for them).

**May it affect the UX to have the action button and tabs too close to each other?**
Moreover, may it confuse the user since the tabs are kind of actions too..though different?

An alternative would be this kind of design:

[image]

Sounds great too, but a lambda user might guess that the Actions would be related to the meeting's schedule, since they are close to it.

**What could be the most appropriate position for the "Actions" button?**
Should I keep the first design, keeping the standard well known iPhone design?

(I forgot the obvious top-left "back" button, in order to return to the meetings list, but it doesn't matter for this OP ;))

Comment: Why are those actions hidden away behind a button and not displayed directly on screen? They are obviously the primary actions in that context.

Comment: Supposing 4 possible actions, wouldn't it take too much place if I show them directly (flat way)?

Comment: What are the four actions?

Comment: But it sounds logic, I agree. Any idea where I could position them? If the user doesn't participate yet, current possibilities are: "Participate", "Mark as Favorite". If he does already participate, actions would be: "Cancel (participation)", "Not marked as favorite". If the user is the meeting's creator: "Edit", "Delete" (removing the meeting completely), "Cancel" (he can cancel its participation even if he's the creator), "Mark as favorite".

Comment: Note that the top-right location (opposite to the back button) would display a Chat button, opening the meeting's user comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need to show your main menu/action bar (all, my meetings and create) in the event detail view. I would instead only **show the actions that are relevant to that context** (actions that the user can perform on the event they are looking at).

Pressing the back button at the top of the event detail view would go back to the event listing, where the main menu bar is shown.

[image]

Comment: Thanks :) I like it. So those buttons would be grouped in a list. Some margins between them?